# Crash reporting in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, crash-reports

Is there a [crash reporting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_reporter) framework that can be used for [pure Python Tkinter applications](http://tkdocs.com/tutorial)? Ideally, it should work cross-platform.

Practically speaking, this is more of 'exception reporting' since the Python interpreter itself hardly crashes.

Here's a sample crash reporter:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Rather than polluting your code with `try..except` everywhere, you should just implement your own except hook by setting `sys.excepthook`. Here is an example:

```
import sys
import traceback

def install_excepthook():
    def my_excepthook(exctype, value, tb):
        s = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb))
        dialog = ErrorReportDialog(None, s)
        dialog.exec_()

    sys.excepthook = my_excepthook
```

Call `install_exception()` when your application starts.

`ErrorReportDialog` is a Qt dialog I've made. `traceback.format_exception()` will format argument passed to the except hook in the same way it does in Python's interpreter.

EDIT: I forgot to mention a little gotcha with that. It doesn't work with threads (well, at least it didn't last time I checked). For code running in another thread, you will need to wrap it in a `try..except` block.

Answer (score 2):

Stick try excepts everywhere your application can crash (I/O, networking etc.). Whenever an except is called, call a function that will kill the old window, spawn a new tkinter notification window, or a [custom one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918752/make-a-tkinter-window-appear-over-all-other-windows) with your error message.

Do a root.after to the new window and send your error report (urllib).

Put a restart button if you wish.

There is no crash reporting framework - as tkinter is not that type of GUI. It's pretty much a wrapper for simple command line apps.

Go pyqt/gtk or wxpython if you want the features seen in the screen-shot above. But I'm pretty sure that where ever you go, you'll have to write your own reporter.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that tkinter is "pretty much a wrapper for simple command line apps". Tkinter is a full fledged GUI library suitable for all sorts of purposes. And in fact, Tkinter can also be used to implement all the features in the screenshot.

Comment: I don't disagree, but if one were to make a full fledged, maintainable GUI (with crash reporting and threads), with the least amount of effort, one would use one of the other toolkits I listed above. The reason they exist is because Tkinter does not fulfil this need adequately.